# Waiting for player input using Node JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, socket.io, wait

I have created a multiplayer poker game for Facebook using HTML5 (client) and Node (server).

I am in the process of writing the server code to allow the player to call, raise, fold, etc. The server sends a message to the HTML5 client requesting the particular player call, raise, etc, but the nature of Javascript is that its non-blocking. I need to make Node wait for the player repsonse before moving on to the next player at the table.

I have had a look at setTimeout, promises, anonymous function and I'm completely lost.

Comment: You're probably going to want a [Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)) of some kind

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is to use web socket.

With WS you can open a connection between client and server.

This connection remains opened until something close it.You can send and receive messages on the socket

Server can send messages to clients and clients can send messages to server

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out a solution to my own problem. I needed to wait for the user to bet before the Javascript code continues. I achieved this by using a Javascript promise and timers.

```
  let bet_marker = false;

  // socket.io response from client
  socket.on('bet', function() {
      bet_marker = true;
  });


  const aPromise = new Promise((accept, reject) => {

    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(sI1);
        reject();
    }, 1000);

    let sI1 = setInterval(function() {
        if(bet_marker == true)
        {
            clearInterval(sI1);
            accept();
        }
    }, 500);
});
try {
    console.log("User Bet");
    await aPromise;
} 
catch(e)
{   
    console.log("Time Ran Out);
    console.log(")
}
```

In my code I create a promise, a setInterval and a setTimeout. The await aPromise statement waits for the promise to call the accept() statment before proceeding. The setInterval function looks every 500ms to see if bet_marker variable has changed. This only changes when a bet is recieved from the client. Once changed we know a bet has been received and the accept() function is called completing the promise. I also have a setTimeout statement in the code that will call that will reject the promise after 10000ms (10s). This gives the player 10 seconds to respond with their bet, but will automatically fold the user if no bet has been received in that time.

I hope that makes sense as I am not a professional programmer...

Answer (score -1):

I would just call the next player's "run" function after the current player has made their move.

No need for Promises or anonymous functions.